# how to move this navigation bar to the right 2

Tags: html, css, button

Ok, I want to add to the title above, but I can't comment since my reputation is not high enough, and I do not think it is appropriate to provide an answer with a question. Please tell me if I am out of line, and that in the future, if I have a question about a topic, I should just ask a question through the answer button.

Anyway, I tried the solution applied here to moving navbar buttons to the right, and it worked. But something else happened, and while I like what happened, I would like to know how i can prevent the change if it happens again, and I do not want it to happen.

Here is the question:

My NavBar is in my banner on the left. When I add the code below, the nav bar shifts to the right, but it drops below the gradient of the banner. Does anybody know why?

This is my code for HTML:

```
     <header class="banner" role="banner">
   <h1>Good Karma Bikes</h1>
   <ul class="NavBarButtons">
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Need a Bike?</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Get Involved</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Our Impact</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">What's New</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Donate Now</a></li>
   </ul>
 </header>
```

This is my code for CSS:

```
/* === Code for NavBar Buttons Begin === */
.NavBarButtons {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.NavBarButtons li{
display: inline;
**float: right;**
}
/* === Code for NavBar Buttons Buttons End === */
```

Does anybody know how to prevent this shift to beneath the banner?

Comment: How do I add jsFiddle?

Comment: add a clear div after `ul` in the html `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

Comment: Just put a link to the fiddle that is reproducing your problem.  There are many factors to what could be happening, so an example would help immensely